# Powershell: Task every minute

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I run the following command in PowerShell:
`Schtasks /create /tn "Scheduler Test4" /sc minute /tr "PowerShell -command cp c:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\myCat/main.txt c:/Users/myUsername/Desktop/myCat_backup/"`

It doesn't work. I desire that main.txt gets copied into the backup directory. When I look in myCat_backup/ there is no main.txt, even if I remove the -command flag. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out once I restarted my device, the script started working. Furthermore, I can now create more tasks and Powershell is recognizing the commands created using Schtasks without restarting.

Answer (score 1):

This script will create a sheduled task that runs powershell every minute as the user "System":

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument '-NonInteractive  -NoLogo -NoProfile -command Copy-Item C:\temp\Source\main.txt C:\temp\Target\'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet 
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Scheduler Test' -InputObject $Task -User 'system'
```